# How to listen to changes with a filter on an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to listen to any changes on my filter :

```
<div ng-cloak ng-repeat="test in test | filter: inputSearch"">
</div>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="inputSearch" class="input-search" placeholder="Search" />
```

I can't do a ng-change on my div because of the ng-repeat.
What can do to listen to any changes about the matching of my filter ?

Comment: What do you want do listen to exactly? Do you mean any changes of what is filtered? If so, why not watch for changes on the input? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot watch a *filter* for changes. You can, however, as AndreM96 said in the comments, watch for a change in your `<input>` search box. Simply specify the following:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-change="onSearch()" ng-model="inputSearch" class="input-search" placeholder="Search" />
```

Then in your `onSearch()` function you can do whatever logic you're trying to do. It will run every time the input box is changed. (and by association, every time the filter is used)